# How to make robot pepper to always stay in one position or pose?

Tags: pepper

I have a question if there is a way to keep robot pepper to continuously stay in one pose. For example, to always have its arm spread.

Answer (score 0):

With NAOqi 2.9, you can make an animation that lasts very long with the desired pose at the start and  at the end.

With NAOqi 2.5, you can make an animation with a single frame that loops (with a goToFrame towards at the end), but it will not prevent other commands to interfere with it.

Note that leaving the arms wide spread makes the shoulders warm, so the robot may have difficulties keeping the pose. Try to set the positions of the motor cleverly to reduce the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can either turn off autonomous mode, or if you want to keep it on you can use the motor stiffness box in choregraphe but it will make the robot warm up

Answer (score 0):

you can stop [autonomous movement](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/motion/autonomousmoves-api.html?highlight=autonomous#ALAutonomousMovesProxy::setBackgroundStrategy__ssCR) or try making a timeline with the fps of 0